# Change src attribute for Image element after upload image in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I used upload tool for ASP.NET Core to upload person image, I put an HTML Image element beside the Upload image tool to display the image after upload it.

I invoke `.Success` event for upload tool and used a javascript function to set the `src` attribute for the image element with the uploaded image path. But unfortunately it does not work :(

This is the Image element

```
<img id="imgPerons" src="" width="200" height="250">
```

This is the javascript function:

```
function onSuccess(e) {
    var files = e.files[0];

    if (e.operation == "upload") {
        document.getElementById("imgPerson").src = "~/images/person_photos/image.jpeg";
    }
}
```

I think I have a problem with the path of the image, because I used online images like the following, and It works fine

```
function onSuccess(e) {
    var files = e.files[0];

    if (e.operation == "upload") {
        document.getElementById("imgPerson").src = "https://www.example.com/image.jpeg";
    }
}
```

What's the wrong with the path of the image?

I saved uploaded image in `wwwroot/images/person_photos`

The Image element and the javascript function in the path `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`

Comment: What's the common document root? I mean, you're showing 2 paths there, but neither of them has a common root. We can't give you the relative path you need without it.

Comment: Do you have `UseStaticFiles` call in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: @Alexander Yes I have

Comment: Anyway, in general `./` means "current directory" and `../` means one directory up. So `./image.jpg` means "Look for image.jpg in the same directory as this script". `./../image.png` means "Start in this directory. Go one directory up and look for the image there". When you understand that, it should be pretty simple to traverse the correct relative path and point it to the image. (side note: this is the general way, I don't know anything about asp.net-core / kendo specifics)

Comment: @icecub Thanks for your explanations. As Alexander says the wrong is with ~ sing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `~` sign in javascript code should fix the problem because it's only processed on `ASP.NET Core` side

```
document.getElementById("imgPerson").src = "/images/person_photos/image.jpeg";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarification, It works.

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif I'd add a dot to it: `./images/person_photos/image.jpeg";`. On most systems, this answer will probably work fine. But in some cases, it'll assume you're trying to start all the way from the OS root and not the current directory if you don't include that dot.